# Understanding what happens and why you need a delegate and source for table views

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios6

I have been practicing with `table views` and I know how to create them but I would like to have a better understanding about delegate and source when creating table views.

Can someone explain the need for a delegate and a source when creating table views?

Why do you need them?

What is happening when you connect delegate and source to File’s Owner or `ViewController` and why they need to be connected?

I guess I need a general explanation about delegates and source and what happens when you connect them to File’s Owner or `ViewController`?

Comment: have you even tried to google it? [Delegates and Data Sources](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010810-CH11)

Comment: @peko:because he/she is stackOverflow addicted

Comment: Can you be more specific what actually you wanna ask. No offense man, but a person of a 100+ repo should not be asking such questions.There should be more to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The delegate and data sources allow the tableview to conform to the [MVC design pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), which is a recurring design pattern in Cocoa and Cocoa Touch.

The TableView itself provides the [V]iew part and the delegate provides the [C]ontroller part while the data source provides the [M]odel part.

When you connect the delegate and datasource in the NIB file you are creating this connection visually; you can just as easily do it programmatically.

Comment: Here is where I’m confused, again the way I have seen this done is that you connect both the delegate and source to the same object, to either the File’s Owner or the ViewController how would this conform to the MVC design pattern, should this be really connected to two different objects/classes? Sorry if my question doesn't make too much sense.

Comment: @fs_tigre Yeah I guess the delegate and data source *could* be connected to two different classes, but this is very uncommon.  Normally the delegate and data source objects access the same information so a single class is used.  The delegate pattern is used a great deal in Cocoa/Cocoa Touch, so you should already be familiar with it.  The data source is kinda unique to table views, and really provides an additional delegate, dealing just with the table view content.

Answer (score 2):

Delegate:-
A delegate is an object that acts on behalf of, or in coordination with, another object when that object encounters an event in a program. The delegating object is often a responder object—that is, an object inheriting from NSResponder in AppKit or UIResponder in UIKit—that is responding to a user event. The delegate is an object that is delegated control of the user interface for that event, or is at least asked to interpret the event in an application-specific manner.

Data Source:-
A data source is like a delegate except that, instead of being delegated control of the user interface, it is delegated control of data. A data source is an outlet held by NSView and UIView objects such as table views and outline views that require a source from which to populate their rows of visible data. The data source for a view is usually the same object that acts as its delegate, but it can be any object. As with the delegate, the data source must implement one or more methods of an informal protocol to supply the view with the data it needs and, in more advanced implementations, to handle data that users directly edit in such views.

For Detail info goto
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html

Answer (score 1):

The [UITableViewDataSource](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol is adopted by an object that mediates the application’s data model for a `UITableView` object. The data source provides the table-view object with the information it needs to construct and modify a table view.

```
Example:
```

Whereas a `data source` type object gives data to another object. For example again, the `UITableViewDataSource` `protocol` has methods such as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `numberOfRowsInSection` dictating what should be displayed in the table

The [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) of a `UITableView` object must adopt the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol. Optional methods of the protocol allow the delegate to manage selections, configure section headings and footers, help to delete and reorder cells, and perform other actions.

```
Example :
```

A `delegate` type object responds to actions that another object takes. For example, the `UITableViewDelegate` `protocol` has methods such as `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` for performing actions upon a user selecting a particular row in a `table`.

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to make any connections if you are happy to write the following code:

```
tableview.delegate=self;
tableview.dataSource=self;
```

Comment: Yes, I have actually seen this before is this assigning delegate and dataSource to be itself?

Comment: Dear @fs_tigre, this line of code means that the delegate an dataSource methods will be implemented in that very class where the code is written.
Also suppose if there is another viewcontroller in which you wish to write these methods then you have to simple write:

    `tableview.delegate=otherObject;
`

Answer (score 1):

If your programming language doesn't support multiple inheritance, you must use delegate method. When you implement delegate method, you can use object functions such as super class.  Example :

```
    // define tableview row count
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

// define tableview height
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

}

// define specific tableview cell
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = MyCell();
    return cell;
}
```